# Segmentation fault error (c), I don't know what's wrong?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

I keep getting the segmentation fault error and I can't seem to find what's wrong.

An example for this would be:

Input: 4 bbbb

Output: 2 abab

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a, len, i = 0, count = 0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    len = a;
    char *strn = malloc((len * sizeof(char*)) + 1);
    scanf("%s", strn);

    while (i != len) {
        if (strn[i]=='a' && strn[i+1]=='a') {
            strn[i] = 'b';
            count++;
            i++;
        } else if (strn[i]=='b' && strn[i+1]=='b') {
            strn[i] = 'a';
            count++;
            i++;
        } else {
            i+=2;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n%s\n", count, strn);
    free(strn);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: You probably mean `sizeof(char)` or basically `1`, not `sizeof(char*)` which is the size of a pointer on your system.

Comment: I think you need `while (i < len-1)`, as `i` might get bigger than `len` without ever being equal, and you're accessing one beyond `i`.

Comment: You should set `len = strlen(strn);` after entering the string.

Comment: Fred, thank you! my error is with the while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

For starters this memory allocation

```
char *strn = malloc((len * sizeof(char*)) + 1);
                                  ^^^^^^
```

is incorrect.

It seems you mean

```
char *strn = malloc((len * sizeof(char)) + 1);
```

The condition in the loop

```
while (i != len) {
```

can invoke undefined behavior because the value of the variable `i` can bypass the value equal to the value in the variable `len` due to the else statement

```
    } else {
        i+=2;
    }
```

and using the expression `i + 1` as an index because for example when `i` is equal to `3` then `strn[i + 1]` is equal to the terminating zero `'\0'` and  the else statement will be executed that will increase `i` by `2`.

You could rewrite the while statement like

```
while (i + 1 < len) {
```